# How to get user objects for people that have liked, shared or commented url in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Update: this is in the context of you being the admin of an FB app, and users having explicitly granted you permissions to access their public profile during app onboarding.

Using the Graph API, I can get the following information about a specific URL that was shared on FB:

```
{
  "og_object": {
    "id": "909175285796xxx",
    "description": "Aja jo e (Des Leben is Schee)",
    "title": "Title text",
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-08-24T18:15:41+0000",
    "url": "https://www.xxx.eu/post/cic36z1do000j80nzub5gqd7m"
  },
  "share": {
    "comment_count": 0,
    "share_count": 70
  },
  "id": "https://www.xxx.eu/post/cic36z1do000j80nzub5gqd7m"
}
```

However, it is not clear to me how to further deep-dive into how this specific object is performing. In particular, I am looking at getting an array of user objects (ids) that have liked, shared or commented this post. For example, I have tried getting data from the `likes` endpoint against the `og_object.id` object, like this:

```
/v2.4/909175285796xxx/likes
```

But that only returns an empty array, even though we know people have liked a post with that url:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

Any pointers on how to leverage the graph api to achieve this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Of course you don’t get any user ids – because _privacy_.

Comment: There are numerous endpoints that do return ids, such as app-specific ids. If you are the admin of that app, then you would have access to that info. @CBroe